# Replace url parameters with variables in php

Tags: php

This is my orginal url. now I want to change %username% instead of $username.

$username = "abcd";

https://connectsms.vodafone.com.qa/SMSConnect/SendServlet?application=%username%&password=%password%&content=%message_text%&destination=%gsm%&source=%shortcode%&mask=%mask%

Comment: Very urgent anyone help me

Comment: could you add a simple of you're expect as result ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the str_replace function.

```
$url = 
"https://connectsms.vodafone.com.qa/SMSConnect/SendServlet?application=%username%&password=%password%&content=%message_text%&destination=%gsm%&source=%shortcode%&mask=%mask%";
//define variables
$username = "abcd";
//then
$before = ["%username%","%password%"];
$after = [$username,$password];
$output = 
str_replace($before,$after,$url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the url, you can use str_replace() to put variables instead of certain strings.

```
$new_url = str_replace("%username%" , $username, "http://"."https://connectsms.vodafone.com.qa/SMSConnect/SendServlet?application=%username%&password=%password%&content=%message_text%&destination=%gsm%&source=%shortcode%&mask=%mask%");
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: sir want to change the url parameters like username,password,content,message,destination,source,shortcode,mask etc. is it possible

Comment: Yes it is. You can add array for str_replace. Like:

$new_url = str_replace(["%username%" , "%content%", "%message%" ... ], [$username, $content, $message], "http://"."$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]"."$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");

Alternative way to save your variables in a key => value array and call foreach on it.

like $url_params = [
'%username%' => $username,
'%content%' => $content,
...
];

foreach($url_params as $search => $replace){
str_replace($search, $replace,
"http://"."$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]"."$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
}

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `%username%` instead of `<?php echo $username ?>`

```
 https://connectsms.vodafone.com.qa/SMSConnect/SendServlet?application=<?php echo $username ?>&password=%password%&content=%message_text%&destination=%gsm%&source=%shortcode%&mask=%mask%
```